# What do we call the `bottom bar` of an HTML image slider?

Tags: html, carousel, terminology

English is my second language and I don't know how to call the bottom bar @3 in below snapshot - `bottom navigator` I guess?

[image]

Comment: “Carousel indicators” is one option. Or “carousel controls” or “carousel dots”.

Comment: "Indicator" sounds good. What do you think about "image indicator"?

Comment: “Image indicator” is too ambiguous. Those image slider things are called carousels. I would immediately know what you’re talking about if you said “carousel indicators”, but I most likely woudn’t if you said “image indicators”.

Comment: Agree and thank you. Please post this as an answer so as to be accepted one.

Comment: I refer to those as dot navigation

Comment: Paging/Pagination controls.

Comment: @AaronLavers That sounds more like traditional pagination with numbered pages at the bottom of a page to me.

Comment: @Xufox while I tend to agree, you'll find many existing plugins call it that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming, which is the topic of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Go ahead mate :-) Get on with your coding skill without naming things. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to know a specific term of a thing from a website, you can check the source code (right click → inspect element) as the term is sometimes revealed as a class name or something similar. As far as I can tell they don’t have *one definitive* name, as each site and each carousel library has their own name for them.

These are some acceptable names:

- Carousel indicators
- Carousel controls
- Carousel dots ([Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html))
- Dot navigation
- Carousel bullets (on [shouldiuseacarousel.com](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/))

Answer (score 2):

Well there are two few options:

- **Carousel Controls** *(this is used in bootstrap as a class name)*
- **Indicators** - either **Carousel Indicators** or **Slideshow Indicators** *(this is used in W3.CSS)*

I would think both are just as good in explaining what you mean and they are both used equally as much when talking about those small dots.

*You can also use:*

- **Pagination** - *though this is not as popular, and is mostly used to describe pages and not slideshows*
- **Carousel Dots** - *which sort of explains it visually*